# Is there a way to join things in a drop down slicer on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a drop down slicer where you select a location, but the locations look something like

Royal London
Royal London Hospital
Royal London HSP

and cases like that for every single location where its the same location written in different ways.

Is there a way to tell power bi to group them together in some way?

Changing the source data so it all matches its not an option, so I would have to do this through Power BI if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Select the slicer and go to the Filter Tab and in Advanced Filtering give your criterion

[image]